# Publishing HTML and RichTextField display HTML code - not rendering (2010)

Tags: publishing

I have several custom columns of type "Publishing HTML", and a page layout several controls which point to the columns:

```
<SharePointWebControls:RichTextField
    DisableInputFieldLabel="True"
    FieldName="WheelImage"
    runat="server">
</SharePointWebControls:RichTextField>
```

The problem is that in the end result, the page shows escaped HTML rather than the rendered output I would expect.

Oddly - when it edit mode - they render fine, showing the rendered output. But in the 'reader' view, it shows the raw HTML.

I have also checked the 'edit html source' in edit mode - and it looks fine, like HTML. But the browser source of the output page shows escaped html.

I [found this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneral/thread/a7ab3a61-6643-4a47-a464-fe46b5db1558) describing the same problem, but its not a solution - as this happens on any browser.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

FYI to anyone, [answered on MSDN](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/7f66abe2-7890-479b-b38b-349d3d1937d5):

> When setting up this site - I had added the columns directly to the
>   site, and not to the content type at the root of the site.
>
> When I add tyhe colums to a custom content type - and then add that
>   content type to the site (rather than the individual columns) - it
>   works.
>
> I have no idea why this would result in it rendering encoded HTML, but
>   it seems to have that effect.